# Softlayer API information needed on using SoftLayer_Ticket with subjectId

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have found an example on [how to create a ticket via the Softlayer API](https://softlayer.github.io/python/create_ticket/):

And I have found [the documentation on the `SoftLayer_Ticket` data type](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Ticket):

What I cannot find is a list of "internal identifiers" that the `subjectId` type can use. In the example above `subjectId: 1121` creates a ticket for Hardware Firewall Question (ID 1121), but I do not know where to find the correct `subjectId` for other problems. Can somebody show me where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code to get the subjects IDs is in the same example:

```
import SoftLayer
from pprint import pprint as pp

client = SoftLayer.Client()
subjects = client['Ticket_Subject'].getAllObjects()
pp(subjects)
```

Here the documentation of the method:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Ticket_Subject
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Ticket_Subject/getAllObjects

Regards